# Alter column varchar to json in psql

Tags: json, postgresql, ddl, sqldatatypes

Hi i am trying to convert a column in my table from varchar to json and the table already had some string data. I tried doing that with the below command.

```
Database=# alter table table_name alter column message type json using
message::json;
```

But the command failed with the below error.

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "This" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: This...
```

Note : The message column has a set of words with spaces like below.

```
"This is a message"
```

I am not sure what went wrong. Thanks in advance..

Comment: If your column doesn't contain valid JSON, then why do you want to convert it?

Comment: I just don't want to drop the column and recreate it again. 
 TYPE JSONB USING to_json(message)::JSONB;
And the above command worked without any errors

Comment: The question is: if the column currently doesn't contain valid JSON data, then why convert it at all?

Comment: After altering the  table i am going to add valid json into the column and for the invalid data i will just ignore. But i need the data for future reference so i dont want to delete it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `to_jsonb()` rather than casting:

```
alter table table_name 
  alter column message type jsonb using to_jsonb(message);
```

If you really want to use `json` (although `jsonb` is recommended), then cast the result back to a json type:

```
alter table table_name 
  alter column message type json using to_jsonb(message)::json;
```

But this seems rather strange for a column that doesn't contain "real" json values, only plain strings.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I don't want to drop the column and recreate it again. I need the old data to be present even if it invalid and this command worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I wanna split varchar that have separator each n-character. For example
`varchar "ab,cd,ef,gh" -> json ["ab","cd","ef","gh"]`

First that I do, convert varchar into array with delimiter of comma (",")

```
ALTER table my_table ALTER column my_column TYPE text[] USING string_to_array(my_column,',')
```

Then, convert array of varchar into json (maybe will you use for GraphQL database)

```
ALTER table my_table ALTER column my_column TYPE json USING array_to_json(my_column)
```

That gives me a result of json(array) like ["ab","cd","ef","gh"]

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run the following command below, it will surely convert the field type as well as the previous records, you might also need to update your models file of respective framework so you can work accordingly.

In my case, I was converting saves_states table's column named prev_month_access_counts type from text to json.

```
ALTER TABLE saved_states ALTER COLUMN prev_months_access_counts TYPE jsonb
using       to_jsonb(prev_months_access_counts);
```

Comment: This advice was already given in the accepted answer.  Why bother to post this answer?